# Is that normal to have larger render time with GPU?

Tags: rendering, gpu

I am using Blender 2.79 on Ubuntu 16.04.2. I have gtx610M(closed source drivers installed) and Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-3210M CPU  2.50GHz processor

I have a very simple scene. A cube placed on a plane.
[image: Scene]

I've rendered this scene with 128 samples. 32x32 tiles. With CPU I got it rendered in 25.56 seconds. But when I switch it to GPU I get it rendered in 1 minutes and 7 seconds. I tried increasing the tile size to 256x256 and then I got it in 54 seconds.

Can that be natural? 1 minutes of GPU rendering time for this scene is obviously larger than normal, how about the CPU? Is 25 seconds ideal?

Comment: Gtx610M is a low end card, so it is totally plausible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GPU's are generally a better solution for your renderings. They offer more processing power and that can be harnessed to render your scenes. 
Here your GPU might not be supported or your drivers not in place, If its not any of these, then its your GPU that is and. Get a newer one and it should work :)

Answer (score 1):

When rendering on GPU, the the amount of CUDA cores built the graphics card will make a difference. The more cores, the faster it is to render.

That particular card has a very small number of CUDA cores: 48. Don't expect much of it in terms of rendering speed. (Just for comparison, a high end card like a GTX titan has 2688 CUDA Cores).

Rendering in CPU might be faster and less restrictive in this particular hardware configuration.

https://www.geforce.com/hardware/notebook-gpus/geforce-610m/specifications